# linkedin oauth2.0 authorization invalid client id error

Tags: authorization, linkedin-api, clientid

I am using linkedin api with oauth library. my request  url for authorization is
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization/?client_id=75gq3kju41jx44&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSocial%2Flinkedin%2Fsettings&scope=r_basicprofile%2Cw_share&response_type=code&state=1436579926-c05e44

But it is giving me error of page not found where it is showing me invalid client id.please let me know where I am going wrong.I am working on localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting rid of the page not found, remove '/' before '?'

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=75gq3kju41jx44&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSocial%2Flinkedin%2Fsettings&scope=r_basicprofile%2Cw_share&response_type=code&state=1436579926-c05e44
```

Answer (score 1):

**LinkedIn's OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint is:**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization # <-- no '/' at the end
```

There is no trailing slash in it. You should remove the trailing slash from your request url and it should work.

Final request url:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?client_id=75gq3kju41jx44&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FSocial%2Flinkedin%2Fsettings&scope=r_basicprofile%2Cw_share&response_type=code&state=1436579926-c05e44
```